# php gives error - failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version not supported

Tags: php, http, get

I am trying to get ScannerStatus from an HP scanner with

```
fopen($scannerstatus1,"r");
```

I get errors like

```
Warning: fopen(http://10.0.0.106:80/eSCL/ScannerStatus): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version not supported in /var/www/html/eSCL/ScannerStatus/index.php on line 14
```

I have also tried

```
readfile($scannerstatus1);
```

&

```
file_get_contents($scannerstatus1);
```

but all yield the same error.

I can open the url with a web browser.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I would suggest using cURL, instead of any sort of file function.

Comment: Yea , easy to say, but no example?

Comment: You can also use ``file_get_contents``: https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: as stated in original post file_get_contents gives me the same error. This is what I had originally intended to use , but can not get around the error.